# How to link my local jenkins with my kubernetes engine on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am here for a problem that I have encountered for days to link my local jenkins and my kubernetes cluster hosted on GCP.
I launched this command `gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-devops --zone=us-central1-c`  locally to generate **./kube** folder locally i got a config file associate.
After ,I had to download the kubernetes plugin on jenkins and I then indicated my cluster address and load my config file as a secret file and I get the following error.
I can see it's a permissions problem but I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you for your contribution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F22e.png)

Comment: Please include the actual error message in the question. Linking to an image is not helpful to anyone. The error message indicates that Jenkins isn't using the correct credentials. So you should include information how you configured the k8s plugin on jenkins. That seems to be the root cause of your problems.

Comment: It is probably authorization problem. Can you provide Jenkins configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer ,sorry for my image .Of course,i just upload a secret file(config file of my cluster) in my plugin jenkins like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APm3M.png)

[I don't know how upload my image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APm3M.png)

Comment: Please paste this information as edit to your question. Look at the proper policy of using stackexchange https://serverfault.com/tour.